# ¿Cómo puedo calcular el total de la columna Subtotal y que al darle eliminar a una fila me reste?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //obtenemos el valor de los input
  $('#boton_agregar').click(function() {
    var id = document.getElementById("txt_idServ").value;
    var servicio = document.getElementById("txt_servicio").value;
    var costo = document.getElementById("txt_costo").value;
    var cantidad = document.getElementById("cantidad").value;
    var subTotal = document.getElementById("subTotal").value;
    var i = 0; //contador para asignar id al boton que borrara la fila
    if (cantidad.length == '') {
      swal("Error", "Ingrese un Servicio y cantidad!", "error");
      return;
    }
    var fila = '<tr id="row' + i + '"><td><input name="id_servicio[]" class="form-control"style="width:55px;" \n\
            readonly value="' + id + '"/></td><td>' + servicio + '</td><td>' + costo + '</td>\n\
            <td>' + cantidad + '</td><td><input class="form-control" style="width:65px;" readonly\n\
             id="subTotal_' + id + '" value="' + subTotal + '" /> \n\
            </td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="' + i + '" \n\
            class="btn btn-outline-danger btn_remove" title="Quitar">\n\
            \n\Quitar</button></td></tr>'; //esto seria lo que contendria la fila
    i++;
    $('#listaservicios tr:last').after(fila);
    $("#adicionados").text(""); //esta instruccion limpia el div adicioandos para que no se vayan acumulando
    var nFilas = $("#listaservicios tr").length;
    $("#adicionados").append(nFilas - 1);
    //le resto 1 para no contar la fila del header
    document.getElementById("txt_idServ").value = "";
    document.getElementById("txt_servicio").value = "";
    document.getElementById("txt_costo").value = "";
    document.getElementById("cantidad").value = "";
    document.getElementById("subTotal").value = "";
  });
  $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function() {
    $(this).closest('#listaservicios tr').remove();
    $("#adicionados").text("");
    var nFilas = $("#listaservicios tr").length;
    $("#adicionados").append(nFilas - 1);
  });
});
//multiplica el costo por cantidad y me devuelve en el input subtotal
function multiplicar() {
  try {
    var a = parseFloat(document.getElementById("txt_costo").value) || 0,
      b = parseFloat(document.getElementById("cantidad").value) || 0;
    document.getElementById("subTotal").value = a * b;
  } catch (e) {}
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<table id="AddServicios" class="table table-sm">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">ID</th>
      <th scope="col">Servicio</th>
      <th scope="col">Costo</th>
      <th scope="col">Cantidad</th>
      <th scope="col">SubTotal</th>
      <th scope="col">Acción</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control col-lg-5" id="txt_idServ" data-name="s" disabled></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control col-lg-8" id="txt_servicio" data-name="s"></td>
      <td><input type="text" oninput="multiplicar()" class="form-control col-lg-5" id="txt_costo" data-name="s" ></td>
      <td><input type="number" oninput="multiplicar()" class="form-control col-lg-5" id="cantidad" data-name="s"></td>
      <td><input class="form-control col-lg-6" id="subTotal" data-name="s"  type="number"></td>
      <td><button type="button" class=" form-control btn btn-outline-success " id="boton_agregar" title="Agregar">
                                            Agregar
                                        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<label>Servicios Relaizados: </label>
<div id="adicionados"></div>
<table id="listaservicios" class="table table-sm">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">ID</th>
      <th scope="col">Servicio</th>
      <th scope="col">Costo</th>
      <th scope="col">Cantidad</th>
      <th scope="col">SubTotal</th>
      <th scope="col">Acción</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
  <input placeholder="Total" name="total" style="width:150px;" class="form-control" id="Total" data-name="s" readonly type="text">
</div>

<div class="form-row">
  <label class="is-required">Observación</label>
  <textarea name="observacion" class="form-control margin-button" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3"></textarea>
</div>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary ">Registrar</button>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

He estado investigando cómo puedo sumar una columna pero no logro implementarlo en mi código y también quisiera que al eliminar una fila me pueda restar lo que tenía y que el total me lo asigne al `input` total.
Les dejo mi codigo compilado para que me puedan ayudar por favor.
Imagen de referencia:

[image: Imagen de mi interfaz]

Este es mi código JavaScript en el que agrego las filas y multiplico el total por la cantidad para obtener el subtotal. Y esta es mi tabla donde se agregan las filas.

En la parte de agregar saco los registros de la base de datos y los asigno a los `inputs`.

Comment: Hola estimado, tienes que poner tu código, de esta forma podremos ayudarte.

Comment: Estimado ya lo puse todo el codigo, lo puede probar por favor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Espero te sea de utilidad; puse  `++++++++++++++` donde se realizo cambio o comentario de mi aportación a tu código.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //obtenemos el valor de los input
  $('#boton_agregar').click(function() {
    var id = document.getElementById("txt_idServ").value;
    var servicio = document.getElementById("txt_servicio").value;
    var costo = document.getElementById("txt_costo").value;
    var cantidad = document.getElementById("cantidad").value;
    var subTotal = document.getElementById("subTotal").value;
    var i = 0; //contador para asignar id al boton que borrara la fila
    if (cantidad.length == '') {
      swal("Error", "Ingrese un Servicio y cantidad!", "error");
      return;
    }
    var fila = '<tr id="row' + i + '"><td><input name="id_servicio[]" class="form-control"style="width:55px;" \n\
            readonly value="' + id + '"/></td><td>' + servicio + '</td><td>' + costo + '</td>\n\
            <td>' + cantidad + '</td><td><input class="form-control elSubTotal" style="width:65px;" readonly\n\
             id="subTotal_' + id + '" value="' + subTotal + '" /> \n\
            </td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="' + i + '" \n\
            class="btn btn-outline-danger btn_remove" title="Quitar">\n\
            \n\Quitar</button></td></tr>'; //esto seria lo que contendria la fila
            //  ++++++++++++++ Mira en class del input que corresponde al SubTotal
    i++;
    $('#listaservicios tr:last').after(fila);
    $("#adicionados").text(""); //esta instruccion limpia el div adicioandos para que no se vayan acumulando
    var nFilas = $("#listaservicios tr").length;
    $("#adicionados").append(nFilas - 1);
    //le resto 1 para no contar la fila del header
    document.getElementById("txt_idServ").value = "";
    document.getElementById("txt_servicio").value = "";
    document.getElementById("txt_costo").value = "";
    document.getElementById("cantidad").value = "";
    document.getElementById("subTotal").value = "";
    
    // ++++++++++++++ Llamamos la función para calcular de nuevo
    actualizarTotal();
    
  });
  $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function() {
    $(this).closest('#listaservicios tr').remove();
    $("#adicionados").text("");
    var nFilas = $("#listaservicios tr").length;
    $("#adicionados").append(nFilas - 1);
    // ++++++++++++++ Llamamos la función para calcular de nuevo
    actualizarTotal();
  });
});
//multiplica el costo por cantidad y me devuelve en el input subtotal
function multiplicar() {
  try {
    var a = parseFloat(document.getElementById("txt_costo").value) || 0,
      b = parseFloat(document.getElementById("cantidad").value) || 0;
    document.getElementById("subTotal").value = a * b;
  } catch (e) {}
}


// ++++++++++++++ Agregado Actualizar
function actualizarTotal() {
  // Se considera la columan Subtotal para la sumatoria.
  // PAra ello, a la propiedad class de los input que corresponden a SubTotal le puse "elSubTotal" (aún que no es clase, ni esta declarada)
  // Usando jQuery
  var sumatoria=0;
  $('#Total').val(sumatoria); // Establecemos a Cero el SubTotal
  
  // Buscamos todos los SubTotales por medio de su "clases" :D
  $.each($('.elSubTotal'), function ( i, val ) {
    sumatoria+=Number($(this).val()); // Se asume todos son número valido
  });
  
  $('#Total').val(sumatoria); // Colocamos el valor final
  
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<table id="AddServicios" class="table table-sm">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">ID</th>
      <th scope="col">Servicio</th>
      <th scope="col">Costo</th>
      <th scope="col">Cantidad</th>
      <th scope="col">SubTotal</th>
      <th scope="col">Acción</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control col-lg-5" id="txt_idServ" data-name="s" disabled></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control col-lg-8" id="txt_servicio" data-name="s"></td>
      <td><input type="text" oninput="multiplicar()" class="form-control col-lg-5" id="txt_costo" data-name="s" ></td>
      <td><input type="number" oninput="multiplicar()" class="form-control col-lg-5" id="cantidad" data-name="s"></td>
      <td><input class="form-control col-lg-6" id="subTotal" data-name="s"  type="number"></td>
      <td><button type="button" class=" form-control btn btn-outline-success " id="boton_agregar" title="Agregar">
                                            Agregar
                                        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<label>Servicios Relaizados: </label>
<div id="adicionados"></div>
<table id="listaservicios" class="table table-sm">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">ID</th>
      <th scope="col">Servicio</th>
      <th scope="col">Costo</th>
      <th scope="col">Cantidad</th>
      <th scope="col">SubTotal</th>
      <th scope="col">Acción</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
  <input placeholder="Total" name="total" style="width:150px;" class="form-control" id="Total" data-name="s" readonly type="text">
</div>

<div class="form-row">
  <label class="is-required">Observación</label>
  <textarea name="observacion" class="form-control margin-button" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3"></textarea>
</div>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary ">Registrar</button>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Es justo lo que estaba buscando amigo, muchas gracias